# Not sure with my probability understanding

Tags: probability

I have here a problem that I am trying to solve but I am stuck somewhere and I am not sure if i am doing it right or not.

> Erin has some coins in her pockets. In her left pocket she has 1
>   nickel and 2 dimes. In her right pocket she has 4 nickels and 1 dime.
>   If Erin takes one coin out of each pocket, what's the likelihood that
>   neither one is a nickel?

```
Given:

 Left Pocket
1 nickel
2 dimes

     Right Pocket
4 nickels
1 dime
```

What i have done so far was determining each pockets that are not nickel.

Left pocket: 2/3 are dimes, Right pocket: 1/5 are dimes then i used this formula.

```
P(both not nickel) = P(not nickel) × P(not nickel) = 2/3 x 1/5 = 2/15
```

problem says there should be one nickel so i used this formula next (i have doubts with this formula i used as Erin would take out 2 coins, but i don't know what is the formula for it).

```
P(at least one nickel ) = 1 − P(both not nickel) = 1 - 2/15 = 13/15
```

I am not sure if `13/15` is the answer to this, I know i did something wrong within the formula but i don't know where. Please bear with me as I am still learning about this. Any help or advice will be gladly accepted. Thanks in advance.

Comment: edited it to 1. a typo on my part.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your answer of $\frac 2{15}$ for neither one being a nickel is correct. It appears there is a second part asking the chance that there is at least one nickel.  Your calculation of this is correct, too, except that the $2$ should be $1$.  The chance of a least one nickel is $1$-chance of no nickels because the cases are disjoint:  exactly one will occur.

You could calculate the chance of at least one nickel by calculating the chance of exactly one and adding to the chance of two.  Given you had done the first part, your approach is easier.

Comment: yes that was my bad it should been 1. a typo on my part. does this mean 13/15 is the correct answer?

Comment: Yes, $13/15$ is correct.  Your logic is right on in both parts.

Comment: i am just confused of the taking of one coin of each pocket part. does it not change my approach in using the formula i have?

Comment: No, you have two separate events:  the coin from the left pocket and the coin from the right.  To have neither be a nickel, you need two successes.  The chance of both is the product of the probabilities of each.

Comment: I am currently answering this from an online homework pre-made by my instructor. i just submitted my 13/15 answer and it was marked as a wrong answer. I am now confused on what happened back there. If 13/15 is not the answer, what should it be? I am blanked out now.

Comment: You didn't quote the second part.  Maybe it is asking for the chance of exactly one nickel?  $13/15$ is the chance of at least one.  Maybe there is an error in the answer key.

Comment: i got it now.... 2/15 should have been my answer. Thanks alot. I have learned alot from this. I was careless

Answer (score 1):

The probability of pulling out at least 1 nickel = 1-P(No Nickels), which you have already calculated. The answer you got is correct.